# JQuery Multi-filter

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a list of post from custom-post-type.
Foreach post, I display title, statut and cat :

```
<div class="adherents">
    <article class="adh-1185 association work adh">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="metas">
            <span>Address</span>
            <br><span>Statut : Association</span>                               
            <br><span>Catégorie(s) : Work</span>                            
        </div>              
    </article>
    <article class="adh-1346 enterprise work adh">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="metas">
            <span>Address</span>
            <br><span>Statut : Enterprise</span>
            <br><span>Catégorie(s) : Work</span>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="adh-1187 enterprise education adh">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="metas">
            <span>Address</span>
            <br><span>Statut : Enterprise</span>
            <br><span>Catégorie(s) : Education</span>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="adh-1347 other health adh">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="metas">
            <span>Address</span>
            <br><span>Statut : Othr</span>
            <br><span>Catégorie(s) : Health</span>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery :

```
$('.todo input').click( function() {
    var statut = $(this).val();
    var statut = "."+statut;

    if( $(this).is(':checked')){
         $(statut).addClass('checked');
         $('.adh').not('.checked').hide();
         $(statut).show();

    }else{
        //Show all if nothing is checked</strike>
    }

});
```

And here are my filters :

```
<div class="filtres">
    <div class="statuts">
        <h3>Statut(s) :</h3>
            <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="association" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Association</div>
            </label>
            <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="enterprise" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Enterprise</div>
            </label>
            <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="other" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Other</div>
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="categories">
        <h3>Categorie(s) :</h3>
            <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="work" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Work</div>
            </label>
            <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="education" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Education</div>
            </label>
            <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="health" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Health</div>
            </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My first filter works perfectly, but when I want to do multifilter statut and categories. Not works... The click show the categorie I clicked but not hide the another categories or hide another filters previously checked. Any idea ?

For example, when I check Statut 1, Statut 2 and Categorie 1, I would like to display all articles from Statut 1, Statut 2 on Categorie 2 and hide anothers.

Users can filter by categorie or statut or statut and category by multifilter

<strike>[SOLVED]Second question : How can I display all articles if nothing is checked ?</strike>

Comment: when you say "not works" please can you elaborate and explain the issue (update the question with that info)

Comment: @JonScott For example, I would like to have all post from "Statuts 1 & 2" but only from "Categorie 2". Actually, when I click on the second filter, this one doesn't filter my articles.

Comment: @JonScott Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code, it should do what you want:

```
$('.todo input').click(function() {
  $('.adh').hide();
  $('.todo input:checked').each(function() {
    var statut = $(this).val();
    statut = "." + statut;

    if ($(this).parent().parents('.categories').length) {
      $('.adh:visible:not('+statut+')').hide();
    } else {
      $(statut).show();
    }
  })

  if ($('.todo input:checked').length == 0) {
    $('.adh').show();
  }

});
```

It uses `.each()` to loop over all `'.todo input` that is `:checked`.

**demo**

```js
$('.todo input').click(function() {
  $('.adh').hide();
  $('.todo input:checked').each(function() {
    var statut = $(this).val();
    statut = "." + statut;

    if ($(this).parent().parents('.categories').length) {
      $('.adh:visible:not('+statut+')').hide();
    } else {
      $(statut).show();
    }
  })

  if ($('.todo input:checked').length == 0) {
    $('.adh').show();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="adherents">
  <article class="adh-1185 statut1 categorie1 adh">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="metas">
      <span>Address</span>
      <br><span>Statut : statut1</span>
      <br><span>Catégorie(s) : categorie1</span>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="adh-1346 statut2 categorie3 adh">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="metas">
      <span>Address</span>
      <br><span>Statut : statut2</span>
      <br><span>Catégorie(s) : categorie3</span>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="adh-1187 statut2 categorie2 adh">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="metas">
      <span>Address</span>
      <br><span>Statut : statut2</span>
      <br><span>Catégorie(s) : categorie2</span>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="adh-1347 statut3 categorie1 adh">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="metas">
      <span>Address</span>
      <br><span>Statut : statut3</span>
      <br><span>Catégorie(s) : categorie1</span>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="filtres">
  <div class="statuts">
    <h3>Statut(s) :</h3>
    <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="statut1" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Statut 1</div>
            </label>
    <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="statut2" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Statut 2</div>
            </label>
    <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="statut3" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Statut 3</div>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="categories">
    <h3>Categorie(s) :</h3>
    <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="categorie1" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Catégorie 1</div>
            </label>
    <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="categorie2" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Catégorie 2</div>
            </label>
    <label class="todo">
                <input class="todo__state" value="categorie3" type="checkbox">
                <div class="todo__text">Catégorie 3</div>
            </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Reitrac if you select Status 2 it should show all status 1 and status 2?

Comment: if I select Statut 2, i should show only Statuts 2. If I check Statut 2 and Statut 1, should show Statut 1 and Statut 2. When I check Statut 1, Statut 2 and Categorie 2 It should show Statut 1 and Statut 2 that have Categorie 2 only.

Comment: @Reitrac Try check it now

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I click on the second filter, not hide another articles

Comment: @Reitrac Not sure i follow you. When i click Statut 1 and statut 2, then it shows 3 items in total. Then when i click Categorie 1 and shows only 1 in total. Please explain better what you desire.

Comment: IOups sorry.. It works with your example, but when I add it to my JS, this not works...  I have the same code as you, i'll try to find the solution, thanks !

Comment: Please note that all your checkbox has the value `categorie1`

Comment: The problem is that my categories are not named as "categorie1" but "enterprise", "association" etc ... So the "indexOf() can't find them

Comment: @Reitrac And how on earth did you expect us to know that?

Comment: Ho sorry I forgot the information ... Your new update hide all my articles. Thanks for your time and your help !

Comment: You are using .parent but there are no parent filter. Users can filter by categorie or statut or statut and category by multifilter

Comment: Any idea ? I really need help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.todo input').click(function() {
        var show_statuts = [];
        var show_categories = [];
        $('.adh').hide();
        $('.statuts input:checked').each(function() {
            statut = $(this).val();
            show_statuts.push(statut) ;

        });
        $('.categories input:checked').each(function() {
            categorie = $(this).val();
            show_categories.push(categorie);
        });

        if($('.todo input:checked').length == 0){
            $('.adh').show();
        }else if($('.categories input:checked').length == 0){
            $.each(show_statuts, function( index, value ) {
                $('.'+value).show();
            });
        }else{
            $.each(show_categories, function( index, categorie_value ) {
                if(show_statuts.length == 0){
                    $('.'+categorie_value).show();
                }else{
                    $.each(show_statuts, function( index, statuts_value )   {
                        if($('.'+statuts_value).hasClass(categorie_value)){
                            $('.'+statuts_value+'.'+categorie_value).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        }

    });
})

</script>
<div class="filtres ">
<div class="statuts">
    <h3>Statut(s) :</h3>
    <label class="todo">
        <input class="todo__state" value="statut1" type="checkbox">
        <div class="todo__text">Statut 1</div>
    </label>
    <label class="todo">
        <input class="todo__state" value="statut2" type="checkbox">
        <div class="todo__text">Statut 2</div>
    </label>
    <label class="todo">
        <input class="todo__state" value="statut3" type="checkbox">
        <div class="todo__text">Statut 3</div>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="categories">
    <h3>Categorie(s) :</h3>
    <label class="todo">
        <input class="todo__state" value="categorie1" type="checkbox">
        <div class="todo__text">Catégorie 1</div>
    </label>
    <label class="todo">
        <input class="todo__state" value="categorie2" type="checkbox">
        <div class="todo__text">Catégorie 2</div>
    </label>
    <label class="todo">
        <input class="todo__state" value="categorie3" type="checkbox">
        <div class="todo__text">Catégorie 3</div>
    </label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="adherents">
<article class="adh-1185 statut1 categorie1 adh">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="metas">
        <span>Address</span>
        <br><span>Statut : statut1</span>
        <br><span>Catégorie(s) : categorie1</span>
    </div>
</article>
<article class="adh-1346 statut2 categorie3 adh">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="metas">
        <span>Address</span>
        <br><span>Statut : statut2</span>
        <br><span>Catégorie(s) : categorie3</span>
    </div>
</article>
<article class="adh-1187 statut2 categorie2 adh">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="metas">
        <span>Address</span>
        <br><span>Statut : statut2</span>
        <br><span>Catégorie(s) : categorie2</span>
    </div>
</article>
<article class="adh-1347 statut3 categorie1 adh">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="metas">
        <span>Address</span>
        <br><span>Statut : statut3</span>
        <br><span>Catégorie(s) : categorie1</span>
    </div>
</article>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I click on the second filter, not hide another articles

Comment: @Reitrac I have made some edits in the script. try it

Comment: Same problem as Carsten. This hide all my articles when I check Categorie input after Statut input. Information : my categories are not named as "categorie1" but "enterprise", "association" etc ...

Comment: @Reitrac which is the parent filter `categorie` or `status` ?

Comment: Humm there are no parent filter. Users can filter by categorie or statut or statut and category by multifilter